# Guzzle 5 Request as cURL String

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

is there a way to get the complete Guzzle request as a string like it would be resolved as a cURL request? (Like the "copy as cURL request" option in the dev tools from Chrome or Firefox).

I know there is a library called "Cuzzle" (https://github.com/namshi/cuzzle), but it needs Guzzle 4 and I'm using version 5.

Any tips or help are appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Fabian

Comment: I need the cURL request string for debug purposes

Answer (score 1):

- [Cuzzle 1.2.1](https://github.com/namshi/cuzzle/tree/1.2.1) works with both Guzzle 4 and 5!
- [Cuzzle 2.x](https://github.com/namshi/cuzzle/tree/2.0.3) works with Guzzle 6.

---

Usage (for version 1.2.1, or Guzzle 5, as in OP's original question):

```
use Namshi\Cuzzle\Formatter\CurlFormatter;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;

$request = new Request('GET', 'example.local');

echo (new CurlFormatter())->format($request);
```